# Como fazer uma comparação direta entre strings tratadas com RegEx no C# diretamente

Tags: c#

Olá, venho da web (javascript) e tenho o costume de trabalhar com OO misturando um pouco de paradigma funcional. Imaginem a seguinte situação.

- Tenho um cpf que tenho que verificar se existe na base de dados;
- Não tenho controle sobre a formatação, então faço um tratamento para remover sua máscara e verificar o que sobrou;
- A partir disso, eu acesso um `DbContext` usando EntityFramework, e verifico, com base no resultado de um Regex se o CPF existe ou não na base de dados.

Normalmente na web eu faria algo do tipo:

```js
var list = [ ... ]; // aqui seria um mockup do banco de cpf's ou o retorno
                    // de um webservice, etc...

var cpf = '000.000.000-00';

function exists(cpf, list) {
    var rx = /[-/.]/g;
    return list.filter(x => x.replace(rx,'') === cpf.replace(rx,'')).length > 0;
}

console.log(exists(cpf, list));
```

Mas ao tentar fazer algo parecido em C# estou tendo uma mensagem que não posso comparar o resultado de 2 regex diretamente. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
// classe DbContext
public class Db: DbContext 
{
    public virtual DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
}

// classe Model (de acesso ao banco de dados)
public class Pessoa 
{
    // propriedades (reduzidas para brevidade)
    public string Cpf { get; set; }

    // método de consulta
    public bool exists(string cpf)
    {
        using (var db = new Db())
        {
            var rx = new Regex("[-/.]+");
            return db.Pessoa.Where(x => rx.Replace(x.Cpf).Equals(rx.replace(cpf,""))).First() != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Não é possível fazer comparações com regex em c# ou a forma que fiz não está clara?

Comment: Já tive problemas assim usando expressões no `Where`, talvez montar diferente resolva, algo como `var pessoa = (from p in db.Pessoa where rx.Replace(x.Cpf).Equals(rx.replace(cpf,"")) select p).First()`

Comment: regex pra verificar se existe ? se já limpou a string, basta verificar... `db.Pessoa.Any(x => x.Cpf == _cpf)`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis a idéia é exatamente não fazer a limpeza fora, mas aproveitar isso dentro do Linq... mesmo asim vou tentar com o `.Any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode comparar 2 regex sim, talvez o problema é que seu segundo `Replace` está com o `r` minusculo.

Se você só quer checar se existe, use o `.Any` ao invés do `.Where`:

```
// método de consulta
public bool exists(string cpf)
{
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        var rx = new Regex("[-/.]+");
        return db.Pessoa.Any(x => rx.Replace(x.Cpf).Equals(rx.Replace(cpf,"")));
    }
}
```

Recomendo também não utilizar regex para esse tipo de coisa mais simples:

```
private RemoveCpfFormat(string formatedCpf) => formated.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
```

Não sei se você é quem insere neste banco, mas também recomendo manter um padrão de formatação ao inserir.